# How to access Jenkins after enabling require login?

Tags: jenkins

I accidentally turned require login on before adding any users for my Jenkins server. It is on an EC2 instance, is there any way to SSH into the command line and add a user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable security checking in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237002/how-to-disable-security-checking-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this follow the [instructions](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security)

> Stop Jenkins (the easiest way to do this is to kill the servlet
>   container.)
>
> Go to $JENKINS_HOME in the file system and find config.xml file.
>
> Open this file in the editor.
>
> Look for the <useSecurity>true</useSecurity> element in this file.
>
> Replace true with false
>
> Remove the elements authorizationStrategy and securityRealm
>
> Start Jenkins