# How to disable security checking in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

In any answer and in jenkins website tell me to set

```
<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
```

in config.xml but in my jenkins folder don't have this file

[image: list of file in /var/lib/jenkins]

Comment: What is the value for the $JENKINS_HOME variable? Maybe /var/lib/jenkins is not your Jenkins home folder.

Comment: I saw result in ps -aux that tell me JENKINS_HOME is /var/lib/jenkins  
`/usr/bin/daemon --name=jenkins --inherit --env=JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins --output=/var/lo
jenkins`  
`/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cac`

Answer (score 1):

`config.xml` doesn't get written until server is restarted at least once since installation.

Try restarting the Jenkins server.

Comment: I restart my server for many time but `config.xml` don't write in my server.

Answer (score 1):

This likely sounds like invalid Jenkins installation, or the file is in another place pointed by `$JENKINS_HOME` or `$CATALINA_OPTS` (e.g. `~/.jenkins` or `/var/usr/jenkins/.jenkins`).

Another reason could be that by default Jenkins load all data from memory and you need to reload the configuration files from file system, so try restarting Jenkins.

Then double check in *System Properties* (at `/systemInfo`) that `user.home` points to the folder where you expect that file. Check also your *System Log* (`/log/all`) for any issues.

If above won't help, check the folder permission and if there is enough space (but you should have some error anyway). Or try reinstalling Jenkins.

According to [*Administering Jenkins*](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) documentation page, the `config.xml` Jenkins root configuration should be always in your `JENKINS_HOME` folder.

---

Once you've got `config.xml`, to disable security remove the lines with `useSecurity` and `authorizationStrategy` and restart Jenkins, or try executing these commands:

```
sudo ex +g/useSecurity/d +g/authorizationStrategy/d -scwq /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart
```